# R: Propensity score with matchit package for data with variables specific to subgroups

Tags: r, propensity-score-matching

I have a database with about 20 variables, four specific to a particular subgroup. For these four variables, I have marked as missing data the data for the other groups.
The first step of my study is to do a propensity score matching with a genetic algorithm. What is the best solution for this problem, knowing that the matchit package does not allow to work on variables with missing values

Comment: Can you do matching separately within each subgroup?

Comment: Yes. If there is no other solution, I will do so since it is systematically missing data, and I did not find any way to deal with this issue for propensity score matching.